# Groovy spread-dot operator

Tags: groovy

I'm unsure about when exactly I need to use the spread-dot operator. If I have a list such as:

```
def animals = ['ant', 'buffalo', 'canary', 'dog']
```

Because both `animals` and the members of the list have a size() method, then in order to have the method invoked on the elements of the list (rather than the list itself), I need to use:

```
animals*.size()
```

rather than:

```
animals.size()
```

However, consider the following expression which returns a list of the method names that are available on the String class

```
String.metaClass.methods.name
```

How does Groovy know (without using the spread-dot operator) that I want the `name` property to be retrieved from each element of the list returned by `String.metaClass.methods`, rather than the list itself? Is there a set of rules to use in this case such as:

- If method/property exists on List, invoke it on List
- Otherwise try to invoke it for each element of List

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Es magico                   .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that [DefaultGroovyMethods adds a "getAt" method to all Collections](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#method.summary) that iterates through the Collection and collects the property value for each.

If you're interested in the long answer, I wrote up a [blog post that dives down the metaClass rabbit hole on this exact topic](http://web.archive.org/web/20170621111648/http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/24/groovy-spread-operator-optional-for-properties-plus-a-peek-into-the-sausage-factory/) a while ago.

Comment: blog post list is broken