# Special Groovy magic re property access and collections / iterables?

Tags: groovy

I understand what is happening here with the spread operator `*.` in Groovy (2.4.3):

```
[].class.methods*.name
=> [add, add, remove, remove, get, ...
```

But why does the leaving the `*` out produce the same results?

```
[].class.methods.name
=> [add, add, remove, remove, get, ...
```

I'd have expected that to be interpreted as accessing the `name` property of the `java.lang.reflect.Method[]` returned by `methods` and so be an error.  But it seems to work.  Having then experimented a bit more, so do the following:

```
[*[].class.methods].name
=> [add, add, remove, remove, get, ...
([].class.methods.toList()).name
=> [add, add, remove, remove, get, ...
```

So it appears attempting to access a property of an array or list (perhaps even `Iterable`) actually returns a list of that property for each element of the list (as the spread operator would).

So this leaves me wondering:

1. Is this behaviour documented anywhere?  (I don't see it here for example: http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html and haven't seen it noted elsewhere in the docs.)
2. Does this behaviour only apply to 'properties' (i.e. non-arg methods following the `getFoo()` naming convention)?  This seems to be the case from some quick GroovyConsole tests.
3. Is the spread operator therefore only necessary/useful when calling non-`getFoo()` style methods or methods with arguments?  (Since you can just use `.` otherwise.)

UPDATE:

It appears to be the case that spread `*.` works for any `Iterable` whereas the `.` only applies to collections.  For example:

```
class Foo implements Iterable {
    public Iterator iterator() { [Long.class, String.class].iterator() }
}
(new Foo())*.name
=> [java.lang.Long, java.lang.String]
(new Foo()).name
=> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: Foo
```

(I guess this is a good thing: if the `Iterable` itself later gained a property with the same name, the code would start returning that (single) property from the `Iterable` - rather than the list property values from the elements.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the GPath expression documented (ish) [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gpath_support), and yes, it only works for properties. (There's an old [blog post by Ted Naleid here](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/24/groovy-spread-operator-optional-for-properties-plus-a-peek-into-the-sausage-factory) about digging in to how it worked in 2008)

For methods, you need to use `*.` or `.collect()`

See also: [Groovy spread-dot operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997345/groovy-spread-dot-operator)

[Better docs link](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#gpath_expressions) (as pointed out by @NathanHughes below

Comment: it's also documented under http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#gpath_expressions, which seems a little more thorough than the first link.