# Groovy implicit spread-dot operator

Tags: groovy, syntax

So, in Groovy, list.elementProp yields the same result as list*.elementProp.

Junior members on the team seem to keep using this feature unintentionally.

I can't find any reference to this behavior in the Groovy docs. Can anyone point me to such documentation?

Edit: The [flagged duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997345/groovy-spread-dot-operator) pertains to how it *works*, not where it is *documented*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy spread-dot operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997345/groovy-spread-dot-operator)

Comment: @cfrick not really, as this is asking for documentation links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's here

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#gpath_expressions

In the GPath expressions section

Comment: Specifically, the statement "property access on a collection is converted to a property access on each element of the collection with the results collected into a collection".

Comment: So what's the purpose of the spread operator then? Or more specifically, how exactly does `asdf*.qwer` differ in purpose or semantics from `asdf.qwer`?

Comment: `listOfThings*.toString()`  would be an example